# sql query to get column of the next row to be of column of a row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write a sql query to get column of the next row to be of column of a row.the test example is as follow:
    table:

```
ID   startno 
1       1             
2       5           
3       9
```

I want to get sql query to get result as follow:

```
ID   startno  endno
1      1         5
2      5         9
3      9         null
```

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RN
FROM TableName)

SELECT T1.ID,T1.startno,T2.startno as endno
FROM CTE T1 LEFT JOIN
     CTE T2 ON T1.RN=(T2.RN-1)
```

You can use `ON T1.ID=(T2.ID-1)` as well. But if the `ID` field is not continuous or missing any `ID`, Join won't work as we exptected. That is why I have used `ROW_NUMBER` to get a continuous series of numbers to join the tables with.

Result:

```
ID  startno endno
1   1       5
2   5       9
3   9       (null)
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49b1b/9)

Comment: could you make the sql little bit simpler?cause' the result table below already includes a' with cte' itself .thanks.

Comment: @stkflmb12: Use any different name then, like `CTE1` or `endtable` or anything. This is the simplest method. If you really want to change it, you will have to use multiple subqueries which will be big in size and lack readability and simplicity. And I won't recommend it.

Comment: it is better to change the 'ORDER BY ID' to   'ORDER BY Startno' in your SQL statement ,'cause startno has its order.

Answer (score 1):

This is [another way of doing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91ad3/1) it:

```
SELECT id, StartNo, 
        (SELECT TOP(1) StartNo 
         FROM Table1 t2 WHERE t2.id > t1.id ORDER BY t2.id) EndNo
FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: ID is not continuous. it needs to make a continuous rowno for each row.

Comment: if the ID is a varchar not a number type.it couldn't compare them，so we couldn't use ID to fix this problem.

Comment: If it is an `Identity` column, it cannot be a varchar in sql-server, otherwise you can convert it to an int. BTW, if it's a varchar field, other answer will have the same issue.